# $this->addError is not working in yii model class

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am trying to do the custom validation.All is working fine except **$this->addError** .
It is not adding the error as it should. this is my controller action

```
public function actionVerifyAnswer()
    {

        if(isset(Yii::app()->session['_emailId']))
        {
        $model=new LoginForm;
        $model->scenario='verifyAns';
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
            $theQuestion=$model->secretQuestion;
            $theAnswer=  strtolower($model->verifyAnswer);
            $usersModel=new Users;

            $emailUser=  Yii::app()->session['_emailId'];

            $userRecord=$usersModel->find('loginEmail=:email AND secretQuestion=:que',array(':email'=>$emailUser,':que'=>$theQuestion));
            if(empty($userRecord))
            {   
                throw new CHttpException('You have selected the wrong question');
            }
            else
            {
                $usersAnswer=  strtolower($userRecord->secretAnswer);
                if($theAnswer === $usersAnswer)
                {

                    $this->redirect('changePassword');
                }
                else
                {

                    throw new CHttpException('you have given the wrong answer');
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            throw new CHttpException('model->validate()');
        }
        }
        else
        {

             $secretQuestion= Yii::app()->params['secretQuestion'];
               $this->render('verifyAnswer', array('model'=>$model,
                                                    'secretQuestion'=>$secretQuestion,

                   ));
        }
        }
        else
        {

           Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
        }

    }
```

and this is my **custom validation** in the model

```
public function checkQuestion()
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())
        {
            $model=new LoginForm;
            $theQuestion=$this->secretQuestion;
            $usersModel=new Users;
            $emailUser=  Yii::app()->session['_emailId'];
            $userRecord=$usersModel->find('loginEmail=:email AND secretQuestion=:que',array(':email'=>$emailUser,':que'=>$theQuestion));
            if(empty($userRecord))
            {   
                //this line is not working

                $this->addError('secretQuestion', 'Incorrect Combination');

                //if i throw exception here. Then exception is working
            }
        }
    }
```

**How can i make $this->addError working?**

Comment: checkout this. May be this can help you http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/2845-adderror-problem/

Comment: i saw it before only but sadly it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue and i am posting the answer because it might help somebody else also.
I needed to remove the

```
else{

//not the code inside

}
```

of this condition

```
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
```

Note:- I just removed the **else and its braces {}** and **left the code inside the** else

**as it was** i.e :-

```
$secretQuestion= Yii::app()->params['secretQuestion'];
               $this->render('verifyAnswer', array('model'=>$model,
                                                    'secretQuestion'=>$secretQuestion,

                   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom validation should be triggered from within the model validate ;

```
 public function rules()
 {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('the_answer', 'checkQuestion'), 
                    ....
    );
}

public function checkQuestion($attribute,$params)
{
      ....
        if(empty($userRecord))
        {   
            //this line is not working

            $this->addError('secretQuestion', 'Incorrect Combination');

            //if i throw exception here. Then exception is working
        }
```

}

Comment: Sir as I have said that when **i am throwing exception, then its working**.so its pretty obvious that i have **already defined the rules** for it

Comment: Where is this in your sample code?  your checkQuestion validation routine is not included in your model validation (it doesn't have parameters required by Yii validation rules).  It's better to add all validation within the model and not try and do it in the controller.

Comment: On another note, from a security aspect, you are holding email_id in the session which could in theory be changed by a hacker.  you should really hold this in your cWebUser class.